# AD groups with upper-case letters are all lower-case if added in wss

Tags: wss-3.0, permissions, active-directory, groups

we are running an wss 3.0 connected to AD.
New Users were directly given permissions to subsites/lists by adding them to the permission list in sharepoint. The users are already in AD security groups so we wanted to change the way we manage users to adding the AD groups to Sharepoint and not single users, because this way its easier to work with for giving/taking permissions.

Our Security Groups look like that:
DP1_Team1
DP1_Team2
DP1_TeamN
DP2_Team1
DP2_TeamN
...

if we now want to add them in SP, the people/group picker shows us those groups as DOMAIN\dpx_teamn. But because the AD groups arent all lower-case, it wont work if i try to login after adding my security group. After changing the name of my group to the all lower-case version in AD, it works.

Is there a way to make it work with upper-case letters or do we have to change all group names to all lower-case to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

AD groups are definitely not case sensitive inside WSS 3 - This issue is definitely being caused by something else.

If you are using Kerberos, you might want to check the upper limit on the Kerberos ticket size - if users are members of more than 100 groups (as a VERY rough estimate), you are likely to start hitting this issue.